# Typing a decorator that curries functions

Tags: annotations, python-3.6, typing

I came across [this interesting snippet](https://gist.github.com/JulienPalard/021f1c7332507d6a494b) on GitHub that curries functions and decided to try to add annotations. So far I have the following.

```
from typing import cast, Callable, TypeVar, Any, Union
from functools import wraps

U = TypeVar('U')

def curry(f: Callable[..., U]) -> Callable[..., U]:
    @wraps(f)
    def curry_f(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Union[Callable[..., U], U]:
        if len(args) + len(kwargs) >= f.__code__.co_argcount:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        # do I need another @wraps(f) here if curry_f is already @wrapped?
        def curried_f(*args2: Any, **kwargs2: Any) -> Any:
            return curry_f(*(args + args2), **{**kwargs, **kwargs2})
        return cast(U, curried_f)
    return curry_f


@curry
def foo(x: int, y: str) -> str:
    return str(x) + ' ' + y


foo(5)
foo(1, 'hello!')
foo(1)('hello!')
```

However, with the last example, Mypy gives the following.

```
curry.py:43: error: "str" not callable
```

I can't seem to come up with a way to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Your type for `curry` is wrong, it doesn't only return `Callable[..., U]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it another `Union[Callable[..., U], U]`?

Comment: In this case yes, but that's because your curried function only has two arguments. It's recursive, which is a problem for typing it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, I think I know what you mean now.