# Typing curried function in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

There is such a function for currying. The problem is that I don’t know how to make this function return a decorated function with the correct types. Help, I have not found a solution anywhere.

```
import functools
import typing as ty
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any, Optional

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable[..., Any])

def curry(func: F, max_argc: Optional[int] = None):
    if max_argc is None:
        max_argc = func.__code__.co_argcount

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args): 
        argc = len(args)
        if argc < max_argc:
            return curry(functools.partial(func, *args), max_argc - argc)
        else:
            return func(*args)
    return ty.cast(F, wrapped)

@curry
def foo(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

foo("df")(5)  # mypy error: Too few arguments for "foo"
              # mypy error: "int" not callable
              # mypy error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  # True
```

How to fix 1, 2 mypy errors?

Comment: A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987933/typing-a-decorator-that-curries-functions) with no answer, and another [discussion in /r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5zl8il/currying_and_pylintmypy/).

Comment: What version of mypy are you using? Your code is working fine on my 0.740.

Comment: I used mypy 0.761.

Comment: returns with its custom mypy plugin provides a solution worth trying https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/curry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, I wouldn't make it a decorator, I'd wrap it as `curry(foo)`. I find it confusing to look at an API where the decorated function signature is different to its initial definition.

On the subject of types, I would be very impressed if the general case is possible with Python type hints. I'm not sure how I'd even do it in Scala. You can do a limited number of cases, using `overload` for functions of two parameters as

```
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
U = TypeVar("U")

@overload
def curry(
    func: Callable[[T1, T2], U],
    max_argc: Optional[int]
) -> Callable[[T1], Callable[[T2], U]]:
    ...
```

adding versions for one, three, four parameters etc. Functions with lots of parameters are code smells anyway, with the exception of varargs, which I'm not sure if it even makes sense to curry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly what I did. Only added overload for one, three, four arguments.

Answer (score 9):

Interestingly enough, i tried the exact same thing, writing a decorator, which would return a curried version of any function, including generic higher-order ones.
I tried to build a `curry` that would allow any partitioning of the input arguments.

## Denial

However, AFAIK it is not possible due to some constraints of the python type system.
I'm struggling to find a generic typesafe approach right now. I mean Haskell lives it, C++ adopted it, Typescript manages to do it as well, so why should python not be able to?

I reached out to `mypy` alternatives such as `pyright`, which has AWESOME maintainers, BUT is stull bound by PEPs, which state that some things are just not possible.

## Anger

When submitting an issue with `pyright` for the last missing piece in my curry-chain, i boiled the issue down to the following (as can be seen in this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/1720)

```py
from typing import TypeVar

from typing_extensions import Protocol

R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)
S = TypeVar("S", contravariant=True)


class ArityOne(Protocol[S, R]):
    def __call__(self, __s: S) -> R:
        ...


def id_f(x: ArityOne[S, R]) -> ArityOne[S, R]:
    return x


X = TypeVar("X")


def identity(x: X) -> X:
    return x


i: int = id_f(identity)(4) # Does not type check, expected type `X`, got type `Literal[4]`
```

Mind the gap, this is a minimal reproducible example of the missing link.

What i initially attempted to do was the following (skipping the actual `curry` implementation, which, in comparison, resembles a walk in the park):

1. Write a `curry` decorator (without types)
2. Define Unary, Binary and Ternary (etc.) `Protocol`s, which is the more modern version of the function type `Callable`. Coincidentally, `Protocol`s can specify type `@overloads` for their `__call__` methods, which brings me to the next point.
3. Define CurriedBinary, CurriedTernary (etc.) using `Protocol`s with type `@overload`ed `__call__` methods.
4. Define type `@overload`s for the `curry` function, e.g. `Binary -> CurriedBinary`, `Ternary -> CurriedTernary`

With this, everything was in place, and it works awesome for fixed-type functions i.e. `int -> int` or `str -> int -> bool`.
I don't have my attempted implementation on hand right now tho'.

*However*, when currying functions such as `map`, or `filter` it fails to match the curried, generic version of the function with the actual types.

## Bargaining

This happens due to how scoping of type variables works. For more details you can take a look at the GitHub issue. It is explained in greater detail there.

Essentially what happens is that the type variable of the generic function-to-be-curried cannot be influenced by the actual type of the data-to-be-passed partially, because there is a `class Protocol` in between, which defines its own scope of type variables.

Trying to wrap or reorganize stuff did not yield fruitful results.

## Depression

I used `Protocol`s there to be able to represent the type of a curried function,
which is not possible with e.g. `Callable`, and although `pyright` displays the type of an overloaded function as `Overload[contract1, contract2, ...]` there is no such symbol, only `@overload`.

So either way there's something that prevents you from expressing the type you want.

It is currently not possible to represent a fully generic typesafe curry function due to limitations of the python type system.

## Acceptance

However, it is possible to compromise on certain features, like generics, or arbitrary partitioning of input arguments.

The following implementation of `curry` works in `pyright 1.1.128`.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, List, Optional, Union


R = TypeVar("R", covariant=True)
S = TypeVar("S", contravariant=True)
T = TypeVar("T", contravariant=True)


def curry(f: Callable[[T, S], R]) -> Callable[[T], Callable[[S], R]]:
    raise Exception()


X = TypeVar("X")
Y = TypeVar("Y")


def function(x: X, y: X) -> X:
    raise Exception()

def to_optional(x: X) -> Optional[X]:
    raise Exception()

def map(f: Callable[[X], Y], xs: List[X]) -> List[Y]:
    raise Exception()


i: int = curry(function)(4)(5)
s: List[Optional[Union[str, int]]] = curry(map)(to_optional)(["dennis", 4])
```